Change auto text selection theme
Does anybody know how to change the auto text selection colour? I have changed the text selection theme as follows:
  TextSelectionThemeData _textSelectionThemeData() {
    return TextSelectionThemeData(
      cursorColor: Colors.deepPurple,
      selectionColor: Colors.deepPurple.withOpacity(0.1),
      selectionHandleColor: Colors.deepPurple,
    );
  }


However, it only applies to manual text selection. When auto text selection happens, it is like in the picture. How can I apply my text selection theme to when the text is automatically selected.
